# How to return jstring from non null-terminated char*?

Tags: java, c++, string, java-native-interface

I have a string represented by char* and length in c++, and I want to return it to Java as a jstring. NewStringUTF accepts c_style null-terminated strings. I know i can copy my string to a buffer and append '\0' to the end, but in consideration of performance, I don't prefer the copy.

```
jstring convert(char* dest, size_t len) {
 ???
}
```

How can I implement this method?
(Java version supposed to be 1.8+)

Comment: *... but in consideration of performance...* How have you **profiled** to **measure** performance?

Comment: If you're really concerned about performance you may want to switch to using null terminated strings.

Comment: not making a copy will introduce another level of complexity in your code, you have to assume (unless in some specific conditions) that the java code has to release the memory of the string after it finished with it, that might be very very difficult indeed.

Comment: "*NewStringUTF accepts c_style null-terminated strings*" - be careful with that. It expected the `char*` string to be in **modified UTF-8** format, not in standard UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Creating the copy on the C++ side is not only the least effort but also the shortest effort.

Here is the best alternative I could come up with:

1. Use `NewByteArray` to allocate a Java `byte[]` of size `len`
2. Fill it with `SetByteArrayRegion`
3. Call `String(byte[], CharSet)` to decode the bytes from UTF-8.

Both step 2 and step 3 create a copy of the string, so you're doing the same amount of work as in your question text, except you're *also* calling into the JVM and allocating extra objects.

In short: just go with your original plan, there is no simpler or faster solution.

Comment: The alternative would be to decode the UTF-8 string into a local UTF-16 buffer, and then use JNI's `NewString()` function using that buffer as input